# Show same dialog twice after dismissing first makes content unresponsive

Tags: android

I hope his can be answered by someone or be able to give me a reason for this behaviour without the code ad really i am not sure where this problem is happening. Here is the scenario that is happening.

I show one dialog that has 2 buttons where each buttons represents an answer. A button is clicked and if you an answer is incorrect then the dialog is dismissed and the same dialog is shown again. The showing of the dialog is done using the Showdialog method(i know it's deprecated but it still works)

The problem that when the second dialog is shown, and the buttons are not responsive. Meaning that they are not click able or are not receiving the clicks events. 
The interesting part that this does no happen on my S2 which has 4.1 but happens on S3 or Nexus that have 4.2.so I am not sure if it is related to android version or where the problem is really happening.

Any pointers? Reallllly appreciate it

Comment: I'm having a similar issue when reusing dialogs after orientation changes.